# Change position of overload bar Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

[image: Example image]

Sometimes when I'm coding, I'm basically copying the line above where I'm writing, so it's a little annoying when this bar decides to show up and doesn't leave until I either click somewhere else or finish writing the line. Is it possible to have this bar appear under where I'm typing instead of over?